# how to make stacked bar graph readable in white and black only

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

I have a stacked bar graph to include in my paper, which is going to be printed by reviewers in black and white only. When I print it out, I cannot tell the difference between some parts of it, which would otherwise be clearly distinguishable in color. Is there any way to make it readable even in black and white? Thanks in advance.

[image: stacked bar]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the function presented in this [File Exchange Pick of the Week](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/07/15/creating-hatched-patches/) to create hatched patterns instead of (or in addition to) your colors.

Here's one example:

[image]

Here's one example of how to use [`applyhatch_pluscolor`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24021):

```
figure, bar(rand(3,4)
[im_hatch,colorlist] = applyhatch_pluscolor(1,'|-.x',1,[1 0 1 1]);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you happen to know how to generate the type of high-contrast figure as the last figure shown [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/24021/2/applyhatch_pluscolor_image.png). I was only able to generate the 3rd one. Please help.

Comment: Oooh, fancy. I might have to pick this one up.

Comment: @sinoTrinity: I have added an example.

Comment: Thanks. I printed it out and it is still hardly readable. My figure is only 0.48 of line width in a two column paper. Worse still, there is legend in it. I tried many combinations of patterns and none worked. Is there any way else to make them readable in black and white only? Maybe use different intensities.